# Firebase Error, application offline (on WebSDK)

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-analytics, sdk

I just create an example for test Firebase Analytics, I worked before with `storage` capabilities and every works fine.

This is my code:

```
<button id="test">Press Me</button>

<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js';
  import {
    getAnalytics,
    logEvent
  } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-analytics.js';

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = await fetch('../firebaseConfig.json')
    .then((response) => response.json());

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  // Initialize Analytics and get a reference to the service
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

  const test = document.getElementById('test');

  test.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('click', analytics);
    logEvent(analytics, 'select_content', {
      content_type: 'image',
      content_id: 'P12453'
    });
  });
</script>
```

My Firebase config includes elements below

```
{
  "apiKey": "xxxx",
  "authDomain": "yyyyy.firebaseapp.com",
  "projectId": "test-firebase-yyyy",
  "storageBucket": "yyyyy.appspot.com",
  "messagingSenderId": "123456789",
  "appId": "1:123465789:web:qazwsxedc",
  "measurementId": "G-qwerty"
}
```

But it throws next error:

> FirebaseError: Installations: Could not process request. Application
> offline. (installations/app-offline).

[image: error message on chrome]

Someone could tell me why ? or where to search? As I mention before `storage` and `cloudstore` are working fine.

Thank you.